# Converting river mile points into a polyline that closely matches the curvature of the stream

Tags: line, curvature

I have a dataset of river miles for all the rivers in Oregon. I am particularly interested in the estuaries on the west coast of Oregon, as I would like to compare sinuosity of the portions of the estuaries that are within tidal reach, and the portions that are entirely fluvial. In the future I may also look into curvature and asymmetry in the meanders as well.

The dataset consists of points at every mile along a river/estuary. Converting these points to a polyline yields a rough trace of the river, but the distances between the vertices means that there are a significant number of straight segments. This is problematic because the vertices are also points of artificially high curvature when they are around meanders, meaning that any value of curvature for a meander would not be accurate.

Is there an approach to creating a polyline from these points, either through interpolation or otherwise, that follows the meanders of the river/estuary accurately enough and has enough points to calculate curvature and asymmetry?

I'm fairly new to coding, but want to build my skillset and understand how to approach problems like this from a computing perspective.

Comment: Why not ignore the river mile points and instead create points from the river flow lines? That way your points would follow the actual river curvature

Comment: To complement @StuSmith, the USA provide for free very detailed river networks that can be found [here](https://www.usgs.gov/core-science-systems/ngp/national-hydrography/national-hydrography-dataset?qt-science_support_page_related_con=0#qt-science_support_page_related_con).

Comment: There is no ArcPy code in your question so I’ve removed your tag for that.